# How to pick a value up to specific value reached in a line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a values in a file like this

```
"AERH1","505549_AdelaideCBDWest_3@505549_AdelaideCBDWest_3",BTS3900,16,16,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
"AERH1","558018_ElizabethVale_3@558018_ElizabethVale_3_UL",BTS3900,448,336,6,1,1,90,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,6,0,6,6,6,6,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,6,6,0,6,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,6,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
"AERH1","505138_Netley_3@505138_Netley_3",BTS3900,448,336,6,1,1,90,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,6,0,6,6,6,6,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,0,6,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,
"AERH1","558012_OneTreeHill_2@558012_OneTreeHill_2_UL",BTS3900,544,400,9,1,1,135,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,0,9,9,9,9,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,9,9,0,0,0,9,9,12,9,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,9,0,9,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

I need to select upto 6 comma's in each line like this

```
"AERH1","505549_AdelaideCBDWest_3@505549_AdelaideCBDWest_3",BTS3900,16,16,1
```

Comment: If you are sure that there are no commas *inside*  the fields (inside the quotes they are legal in csv), you can use the `cut` command with option `-f` for field selection and option `-d ,` to set the comma as field delimiter. See `man cut` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f 1-6 file
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{OFS=","; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' file
```

In both cases the output will be:

```
"AERH1","505549_AdelaideCBDWest_3@505549_AdelaideCBDWest_3",BTS3900,16,16,1
"AERH1","558018_ElizabethVale_3@558018_ElizabethVale_3_UL",BTS3900,448,336,6
"AERH1","505138_Netley_3@505138_Netley_3",BTS3900,448,336,6
"AERH1","558012_OneTreeHill_2@558012_OneTreeHill_2_UL",BTS3900,544,400,9
```

Comment: @Meenakshisundaram, If some answers in this topic was helped you, mark it as solution for future users with the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use awk:

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=1;i<=5;i++) { printf "%s,",$i } printf "%s\n",$6 }' filename
```

Look through each comma separated field up to five printing each field followed by a comma and then finally print the 6th piece.

Answer (score 0):

CSV has some nasty edge cases, so best to use a CSV parser. For example, with Ruby:

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| puts CSV.generate_line(row.first(6))}' file
```